# Кнопки в боте. Как сделать, что бы одновременно отображались инлайн и кнопки меню

Tags: telebot, клавиатура, inline

3 день брожу по интернету и за 8-10 ч в день не смог найти ответа на свой вопрос. Мне необходимо одновременно инлайн кнопки в меню + их сопровождение внизу(клавиатура), пишу на TeleBot
Нужно примерно вот так!
/start
картинка
мой текст
*кнопка инлайн*
и внизу кнопки две
Одновременно!
Пробовал по разному наверно что то очевидное не понимаю, но я уже не надеюсь даже найти ответ.

---

```
import telebot
from telebot import types


bot = telebot.TeleBot('MEOW')

@bot.message_handler(commands="start")
def get_user_text(message):
   if message.text == "/start":
     markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1)
     item1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Саратов', callback_data= 'rage1')
     item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Энгельс', callback_data='rage2')
     markup.add(item1, item2)

     photo = open('11.jpg', 'rb')
     bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption= "Привет, дорогой друг! Из какого ты 
города?" , reply_markup=markup )

@bot.message_handler(commands="start")
def get_user_text(message):
  if message.text == "/start":
     markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
     item3 = types.KeyboardButton('Я не скажу')
     item4 = types.KeyboardButton('Написать самому')
     markup.add(item3, item4)
     photo = open('11.jpg', 'rb')
     bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo, caption="Давай знакомиться!",
                   reply_markup=markup)



  с callback все ок


bot.polling(none_stop='true')
```